# Multiple markers on a map -> How to detect which marker was clicked?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I have multiple markers [Leaflet.js] on an OpenStreetMap and I want to detect which marker was clicked.

Is there a function that would enable me to set a className/id for the markers?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get it like that

```
markers.on('click', function (marker) {
       console.log(marker); /// marker is associated one here
});
```